# Access Profiler without a request on a PHPUnit Symfony2 project

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

How can I access the profile on a unit test context where there is no request? 
In my case, I'm making tests to a  data access layer that uses some other DBAL, doctrine2 in my case, and I want to assure that only a certain number of queries are made for performance issues. Don't want to put http requests in this scenario.

If I just do code below the collectors don't collect anything, and at the last line an exception is throw because `getQueryCount` it tries to access a data member set to null:

```
public function testQueryCount() {

    /* @var $profile Profiler */        
    $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    $profile = $this->getContainer()->get('profiler');
    $profile->enable();

    $eventDataAccess = new EventDataAccess($em);
    $e = $eventDataAccess->DoSomething(1);

    $a = $profile->get('db');
    $numMysqlQueries = $a->getQueryCount();
    $this->assertCount(1, $numMysqlQueries)
}
```

I've got the profiler in the `config_test.yml` with:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        connections:
            default:
                logging: true

framework:
    profiler:
        only_exceptions: false
        collect: true
```

Comment: I barely can call that a *unit* test though. Doesn't look like a good idea either.

Comment: @zerkms, please, don't focus on the "bogus/dummy/incomplete" test, instead please focus on the problem that I've posted. But thanks for the comment I've make a small adaption so it can be more "testable". By the way, think is a perfectly acceptable idea to test how many times a dbal access the database. If lazy loading is active I want to minimize that.